# Svelte run dev not working even after fresh install and node_modules reinstall

Tags: node.js, rollup, svelte-3

I clean installed nodejs and created a svelte project using `npx degit sveltejs/template LeanFire` and then ran `cd LeanFire && npm install`. After multiple attempts on fixing, I still get the same error when I run `npm run dev`.

```
D:\Design & Code\LeanFire>npm run dev

> svelte-app@1.0.0 dev
> rollup -c -w

'Code\LeanFire\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\rollup\dist\bin\rollup'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your package.json?

Comment: @whygee Added package.json to the original post.

Comment: Okay so the problem isn't the package.json. I assume you are using Windows, can you check if node has been added to your window's path environment? Can you also try closing the terminal and opening a new one?

Comment: @whygee I did check. Node is present in PATH (Environment Variables > Path > Edit > C:Program Files: nodejs was present) and I tried using git bash, cmd, and powershell. I still get the exact same error unfortunately.

Comment: It says cannot find module ```'D:\rollup\dist\bin\rollup``` There is no such thing as D:\rollup in the first place. Is the rollup configured wrong or something? Was wondering if there was a way to bring this post to more attention or have it reach more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like npm was having troubles? I deleted the **node_modules** and then used pnpm instead and then ran `pnpm install` and then `pnpm run dev`. For some reason it worked!?

Comment: This worked for me too. After `pnpm install`, I could go with `npm run dev`, which implies that only the installation has failed. Any ideas why?